# ColorFunction ranges for SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d, color

I'm not sure why

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{θ, ϕ}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][
    Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, θ, ϕ]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

looks different to

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, #4, #5]]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

(I don't understand how the # symbols work here.) Which one is correct for plotting this spherical harmonic? But my main question is why do the plots not show the full Rainbow color palette? I would like to plot this spherical harmonic using the full Rainbow color palette from min to max value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

The first question has now been answered. Thank you to all who contributed :-) Here is a simple example to expose my confusion about the color palette (my unanswered question):

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, #4, #5]]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
BarLegend[{ColorData[
    "Rainbow"], {MinValue[{ComplexExpand[
       Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 
         2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]], {0 <= \[Theta] < \[Pi], 
       0 <= \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}], 
    MaxValue[{ComplexExpand[
       Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 
         2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]], {0 <= \[Theta] < \[Pi], 
       0 <= \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}] }}, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row"] // Quiet
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {MinValue[{ComplexExpand[
       Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 
         2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]], {0 <= \[Theta] < \[Pi], 
       0 <= \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}], 
    MaxValue[{ComplexExpand[
       Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 
         2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]], {0 <= \[Theta] < \[Pi], 
       0 <= \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi]}}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}] }}, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row"] // Quiet
```

In this example, I suspect that the color function is scaling from 0 to 1 (the first legend), whereas I want the color function to scale from min to max of whatever I'm plotting (the second legend). How do I achieve this?

Comment: By providing only two arguments you are using the first two slots (`x` and `y`)  irrespective of what name you call them. Consequently, your first plot is equivalent to

`SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, #1, #2]]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This has answered my first question as to why those two lines produce different output, and has also clarified my confusion with the # symbols. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColorFunction` of a `SphericalPlot3D` has six arguments, the first three being the $x$, $y$ , $z$ coodinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The fourth and fifth argument are the actual parameterization parameters of the surface and the last argument is the distance from the origin (the radius).

`#` (`Slot`) and `&` (`Function`) together allow to define anonymous function. `#4` and `#5` refer to the fourth and fifth argument. Here is (essentially) equivalent rewrite with `Function` in long form:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[
   {x, y, z, u, v}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, u, v]]]
   ], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[#, 3] &@
  Table[SphericalPlot3D[
    1 + Sin[5 ϕ]/10, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, Evaluate[f]], 
    PlotLabel -> f, 
    Axes -> None], {f, {Hue[x], Hue[y], Hue[z], Hue[θ], 
     Hue[ϕ], Hue[r]}}],

 ImageSize -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: 6 args -- you forgot the radius

Comment: @BrettChampion Thanks, good point! I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This explains really well how the function works and I am understanding the problem a lot better now. Thank you very much :-) I am able to use Hue to get the full color palette (albeit without a BarLegend...), however how do I get my selected color scheme (e.g. Rainbow) to give me the full color palette? I will edit my question with some more examples. Thank you again for your time

Comment: Just use the color function (i.e. a function from $[0,1]$ to the RGB colors) of your choice instead of `Hue`.

Comment: The works for the simplest of examples, such as x, y, z, theta, phi, etc... But it breaks when I try to apply this to my spherical harmonic:

`SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][
    Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]]]]`

It is the equivalent of me setting ColorFunctionScaling -> True in my original question. Do you have any idea why it works for simple cases but breaks for more complicated cases? (Found this issue in other more complicated functions too :-( )

Comment: You have do deactivate the `ColorFunctionScaling ` and to transform yout color function a bit:`SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][
    Re[SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]] + 0.5
    ]
   ],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]`

Comment: I see, thank you! Yes, this is exactly what I want :-) So I have to manually transform my color function to be in the range 0 to 1 for the more complicated cases. Is there a quick way to do this in mathematica? If not, don't worry, it is simple enough to do manually and you have helped me a lot already. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer yet, but I will do soon :-)

Comment: Hey Bart, you're welcome. I don't know of a simple way. A list of values can be easily transformed affinely into $[0,1]$ with `Rescale`. But I have no clue for functions (and this would actually be not that easy to implement). But something along the lines of `MinMax[Table[
  Re@SphericalHarmonicY[5, 2, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi, 
   0.1}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]]` may give you a hint how to transform. In this case, we see that `0` appears to be roughly in the middle of the range of values, so `+ 0.5` is in order.

Comment: No problem, in that case I will just use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value